# Postfix mysql Temporary lookup failure

Tags: mysql, postfix

I'm trying to configure a postfix/courier/mysql/SquirrelMail setup, using [this guide](http://www.howtoforge.com/virtual-users-and-domains-with-postfix-courier-mysql-and-squirrelmail-ubuntu-12.10), but i get the following error when trying to send an email:

```
451 4.3.0 <info@mydomain.com>: Temporary lookup failure
```

/var/log/mail.log entry:

```
Mar 16 11:37:42 myserver postfix/smtpd[12750]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Mar 16 11:37:42 myserver postfix/smtpd[12750]: warning: connect to mysql server localhost: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
Mar 16 11:37:42 myserver postfix/smtpd[12750]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf lookup error for "info@mydomain.com"
Mar 16 11:37:42 myserver postfix/smtpd[12750]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 451 4.3.0 <info@mydomain.com>: Temporary lookup failure; from=<info@mydomain.com> to=<info@mydomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<webmail.mydomain.com>
Mar 16 11:37:42 myserver postfix/smtpd[12750]: lost connection after RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Mar 16 11:37:42 myserver postfix/smtpd[12750]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
```

I have rechecked the /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf file, and it is configured correctly.

```
user = mypostfixusername
password = mypass
dbname = mail
query = SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='%s'
host = 127.0.0.1
```

My mysql server is running, i can connect to it using mysql -u mypostfixusername -p, and can run queries. I can also login with SquirrelMail.

Comment: Shouldn't the last line in your `/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf` be `hosts = 127.0.0.1`?

Comment: I'm blind, was looking at the files for 2 hours, didn't notice that, thank you very much.

Comment: If we specify `127.0.0.1` postfix should try to connect over `TCP` but your logline says that postfix cant connect to `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`.so that helped. :)

Comment: @masegaloeh done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line in your `/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf` should be

```
hosts = 127.0.0.1
```

instead of

```
host = 127.0.0.1
```

If we specify `127.0.0.1` postfix should try to connect over `TCP` but your logline says that postfix cant connect to `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` and so it didn't recognize the `host = 127.0.0.1` line. Hope that helps.